# Conflicting dependencies

Tags: dependencies, spyder, conflict, watchdog, mkdocs

I recently installed mkdocs (with pip). It requires Spyder 4.2.5, and watchdog >=2. After installing Spyder, the installation process resulted in un-installation of the current watchdog I have installed (2.1.9), and the installation of a lower version (1.0.2).

So there is the issue of conflicting requirements between Mkdocs and Spyder (they require different version of Watchdog). How do I resolve this issue?

Oh, is it by creating a virtual environment?

Then, installing mkdocs and it's required version of Watchdog?

Do I need to still install Spyder in the venv?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think you can't have both mkdocs and Spyder in the same environment because of this conflict.

Comment: So I create a venv then with only installation of mkdocs and watchdog. But in the venv, won't mkdocs still require Spyder? If yes, doesn't that imply I might not be able to make use of mkdocs on my local machine due to this conflicting dependencies?

Comment: `But in the venv, won't mkdocs still require Spyder?` No, mkdocs doesn't need Spyder to work. I think the easiest thing you can do is to create a venv for mkdocs and a different one for Spyder.